# Updating UI when XMPP message arrived

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. In my current project I'm using the asmack library to receive XMPP messages. In my MainActivity I have:

```
Connection connection; // from the asmack library
```

and

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        // HERE! is where I want to update the UI when I receive packets
    }
}
```

The weird thing is when I parse the packet and simply call setText() on two labels. At first nothing happens, but when I touch a Button (hence calling some update routine) only the first label is updated.

Now, as far as I understood you're supposed to use AsyncTask in such cases but this didn't work out either.

Did I misunderstood some core concept? Can someone lead me to the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packet seems to be processed on a separate thread than the UI thread, which means the UI will not be updated immediately since you're not manipulating it on its thread. Therefore, you should do something like this...

```
connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener(){

    public void processPacket(Packet packet){

        //update the UI on its thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()){
            public void run(){
                //update UI elements
            }
        }

    }

}
```